# Are two homotopic principal bundles isomorphic?

Tags: fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $E_1 \to B$ and $E_2 \to B$ be two principal $G$-bundles, where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are two simply-connected manifolds and $G$ is a compact Lie group.

Suppose there exists a $G$-equivariant continuous map $h:E_1 \to E_2$ such that

(a) $h$ is homotopic to a homeomorphism between $E_1$ and $E_2$;

(b) The induced map $h':B \to B$ from $h$ is homotopic to the identity.

Can we prove that $E_1 \to B$ and $E_2 \to B$ are bundle-isomorphic?

Comment: Are you aware of Palais' Covering Homotopy Theorem? https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.45.6.857 It implies that $h$ is isovariantly homotopic to a $G$-map covering the identity. So we may assume $h$ covers the identity.